# Compare array value with user input bash

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, ascii

I'm trying to compare user input with a string array value, when I do so both values seem to be the same when I print them out but the if statement doesn't see them as equal. Is there something obvious I'm missing.

```
k=0
while [ -z $arg1 ]
do
    while [ $k -ne 9 ]
    do
    # ask question
    echo "${question[k]}"
    answer="${answer[k]}"
    read -p "YES/NO " arg1
    # check answer
    if [ '$arg1' = '$answer' ]; # problem is here
    then
        echo "Correct!"
        let "k=$k+1"
    else
        echo "Incorrect!"
        echo "Your answer: $arg1"
        echo "Correct answer: $answer"
    fi
    done
done
```

Comment: Looks like you have an array `answer` which you're then overwriting with a variable containing one of its elements.

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0):

Replace: You have not put what is in answer and question array

```
 if [ '$arg1' = '$answer' ];
 with
 if [ "$arg1" = "$answer" ] ;
```

and check

Comment: Change you statement,  answer="${answer[k]}" to answer_other ="${answer[k]}" and check with if [ "$arg1" = "$answer_other" ] ;

Comment: No still not happy, although I can see what you mean, cause Im using same name for array and variable it cold have got "confused", well not I changed it, it just doesn't make sense

Comment: enable  set -x . This would enable debugging option and provide more insight on what is going wrong